# Ansible is masking strings which matches password with URI module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Using **uri** module to get some data from an API

```
 - name: Fetch Data
    uri:
       url: "https://192.168.1.1:8080/api/data"
       headers:
       timeout: 60
       method: GET
       user: oes
       password: "123"
       force_basic_auth: yes
       status_code: 200
       return_content: yes
       validate_certs: no
    register: response
    ignore_errors: yes
```

The response contains **password** (***123***) which is being masked to ***

```
{
  "Name":"sample",
  "Age":"10",
  "Roll No":"123"
}
```

could someone please help in find a way to avoid masking of password pattern from the response payload

Comment: heh, how about "don't use 123 as a password?!" which, as one might expect, is [directly addressed in the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/network/user_guide/faq.html#why-is-my-output-sometimes-replaced-with)

Comment: well, @MatthewLDaniel I just gave a sample password. I get UUID in response which may not be as simple as 123 and it could match with a GOOD password. So I was thinking if there is a way to avoid masking.

Comment: for your consideration, the second "U" in UUID is supposed to provide reasonable guarantees against collisions, so unless the password _is_ the identifier, I would not expect matches by chance

Answer (score 2):

Having already warned you about the [please don't do that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/network/user_guide/faq.html#why-is-my-output-sometimes-replaced-with) advice in the manual, you can circumvent the problem by tricking ansible into not knowing that `123` is your password:

```
- uri:
    url: https://oes:123@192.168.1.1:8080/api/data
    force_basic_auth: yes
    # etc etc but **omitting** user: and password:
```